# text games I have few problems with the one i am doing for school and would like a little help. at the bottom is the error i am getting when running

Tags: python

```
rooms = {
    'Starting Room': {'name': 'Stating Room', 'south': 'Library', 'east': 'Bedroom', 'west': 'Front Room',
                      'north': 'Dining Room'},
    'Library': {'name': 'Library', 'item': 'sheep', 'north': 'Starting Room', 'east': 'Den'},
    'Den': {'name': 'Den', 'west': 'Library', 'item': 'treats'},
    'Bedroom': {'name': 'Bedroom', 'west': 'Starting Room', 'north': 'Mad Dog', 'item': 'dog bone'},
    'Front Room': {'name': 'Front Room', 'east': 'Starting Room', 'item': 'lamb'},

    'Dining Room': {'name': 'Dining Room', 'south': 'Starting Room', 'east': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'frog'},
    'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'west': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'food'},

    'Mad Dog': {'name': 'Mad Dog'},
}

directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']

current_room = rooms['Starting Room']


user_name: str = input('Enter your name?')
print('\nHello and welcome to the game', (user_name))

rooms = current_room  # starts player in the starting room

inventory = []  # Adds an inventory


def get_item(current_room) -> object:
    if 'item' not in [current_room]:
        return 'This room has no item!'  # return statement
    else:  # if statement
        return rooms[current_room]['item']  # return statement


while True:
    if current_room['name'] == 'Mad Dog':
        print('Congratulations! You have reached the Mad Dog and WON!')
        break
    # display current location
    print('You are in {}.'.format(current_room['name']))
    command: str = input('\nWhat way would you like to go (north,south,east or west) you can exit by typing exit:')
    # movement
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room: dict[str] = rooms['Starting Room']
        else:
            # bad movement
            print('You cannot go that way.')
    # quit games
    elif command == 'Exit':
        print('Thanks for playing hope that you enjoyed the game!')
        break
    # bad command
    else:
        print('you have to enter north, south, east or west')

    if 'item' in inventory:  # if statement
        print('You have already collected this item. Move to another room!')  # print statement
    else:
        inventory.append(item)  # adds item to inventory
        print('Not a valid direction!')  # Print statement
    if len(inventory) == 6:  # if statement

        print(
            'Congratulations!! You have collected all the necessary items and made the Mad Dog HAPPY!')  # print statement
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\alcsj\PycharmProjects\Sample\sample.py", line 48, in
>
> current_room: dict[str] = rooms['Starting Room'] KeyError: 'Starting Room'

Answer (score 0):

You reset the `rooms` variable here:

```
rooms = current_room  # starts player in the starting room
```

That sets it to a specific room, which doesn't have the `'Starting Room'` key. That line should probably be removed, or the `rooms` variable renamed to something else.

(I don't know the function of that line, since `current_room` is already set to the starting room. I think you can remove the line, but it depends on what you were planning to use it for later.)